# Matplotlib pcolor - color relative by columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart, heatmap

I want to create a heatmap of a matrix. I also want to scale the colors for each columns separately. In the example I have, the large values clearly dominate and all the color is there.

What I want is the coloring relative to the columns, so that [1, 2, 3] is colored on the same scale as [1000, 2000, 3000]. (I suppose the solution to this example would be 3 stripes of the same color for three levels).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [10, 20, 30],
              [100, 200, 300],
              [1000, 2000, 3000]]).T
plt.pcolor(d1, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

If this can be solved by another type of chart (e.g. barchart) it also works, as long as I get all squares the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You can normalize each column based on it's sum like this:

`d1 = d1.astype(float) / d1.sum(axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show those values in the same heatmap, you need to change the data first. You may e.g. divide each column by its maximum (called normalizing).

```
d1 = d1.astype(float) / d1.max(axis=0)
```

(here, `axis=0` means the vertical axis of the array.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [10, 20, 30],
              [100, 200, 300],
              [1000, 2000, 3000]]).T
d1 = d1.astype(float) / d1.max(axis=0)
plt.pcolor(d1, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)    
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]